# List folders that contain more than X images

Tags: find

Is there a way to return a list of all folders on a given disk containing more than X images ?

The search should be recursive but X should not.

Example for X=100 :

```
Folder A
|_ folder A1 (containing 100 pictures)
|_ folder A2 (containing 50 pictures)
|_ 50 pictures
```

Should return "Folder A1" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each image, print the name of the directory it lies in:

```
find \( -name \*.png -or -name \*.gif -or -name \*.jpg \) -printf '%h\n' |
```

uniq needs sorted input, but `find` prints files rather randomly. (In my test, even `find -depth` didn't help, don't ask me why.)

```
sort |
```

for every directory name, tell us how often it occurs:

```
uniq -c |
```

and finally, filter the lines we want:

```
while read count dir; do
    if [ "$count" -ge 100 ]; then echo "$count $dir"; fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming all the pictures end with `.png` and `X=100`

```
find ./ -type d -exec sh -c 'count=$(ls "${0}"/*.png | wc -l); if [ "${count}" -ge 100 ];then echo "${0}"; fi ' {} \;
```

**EDIT**

It can be extended for files for any number of `extensions` and any value of `X` like  below

```
export files='png jpg gif'
export X='100'
find ./ -type d -exec \
sh -c 'count=$(for i in ${files}; do ls "${0}"/*.${i};done | wc -l); \
if [ "${count}" -ge "${X}" ];then echo "${0}"; fi ' {} \;
```